# Electrum Wallet Backup and Restore process

Tags: electrum, wallet-recovery, backup

I guess I have misunderstood something somewhere, because this process isn't working quite as I expected. I had electrum on one laptop which I am about to reset, but before doing so, I wanted to be sure everything was backed up and running from another laptop, and now with Electrum, I went to File > Save Backup on the machine that is about to be reset, then installed electrum on the new machine, and when it asked to create a new wallet or import an existing one on its first start up, I gave it the backup file to use over the network, thinking it would then use that to install a local copy, but instead it seems to reference that backup file on the NAS every single time, and it asks for my password to access it every single time it starts ... this doesn't seem like how it should work, what am I doing wrong here?